# How do I output a duplicate letter in a string line?

Tags: php, string, split, output

I have string like `$text = '1234567812349101';` I want to be able to output the repeated letters and how many times they're repeated. For example the expected result should be `This string 1234 is repeated. Repeated 1 times.`

I've tried:

```
$text = '1234567812349101';

$disp = str_split($text, 4);

foreach ($disp as $char) {

    if (preg_match('/(.{4,})\\1{2,}/', $char)) {
        echo "This string $char is repeated. Repeated times.";
    }
}
```

But there's no output.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do the occurrences have to be evenly split into non-overlapping 4-character chunks? i.e. should the string `123451234` display repeating characters?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$text = '1234567812349101';

$disp = str_split($text, 4);

$dupes = array_filter(array_count_values($disp), function ($el) {
    return ($el > 1);
});

foreach ($dupes as $dupe => $times) {
    echo "This string $dupe is repeated. Repeated " . ($times - 1) . " times.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This string 1234 is repeated. Repeated 1 times.
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/923709)

Comment: @David
It pretty nice but can i do this without function and editing my code?
    $text = '1234567812349101';

    $disp = str_split($text, 4);

    foreach ($disp as $char) {

      // achievement code here

Answer (score 0):

```
   $text = '1234567812349101';

   $disp = str_split($text, 4);
   $count = 0;
   foreach($disp as $char){

       if(strcmp("1234",$char)){
           $count++;
       }
   }  
   $cnt = $count-1;
   if($cnt > 1){
    echo "1234 String is repeated. Repeated ".$cnt."times";
   }
```

I hope This will help you out :)

Comment: Yes but you want to compare 1234 ?? or any string from this string??

Comment: @solink If you want to make it more dynamic then 

    `foreach($disp as $char){
      
           if(strcmp($disp[0],$char)){
               $count++;
           }
       }  
       $cnt = $count-1;
       if($cnt > 1){
        echo "1234 String is repeated. Repeated ".$cnt."times";
       }`